# Sqlalchemy join table query to get column names equalized as multi-level columns

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy

First of all, I understand what I want to achieve can be done using pandas dataframe.concat(). However, due to a large amount of data, the computer memory sometimes crashes. So I try to achieve the multi-table join by saving those tables into db via sqlalchemy. 
I will explain what my goal is by giving the simple example below.

**table: Case0**

[image]

**table: Case1**

[image]

what I want to achieve is something like this by a python sqlalchemy query (**NOT** pandas):
[image]

```
import pandas as pd 

lst1 = ['Apple', 'Banana'] 
lst2 = ['Pink', 'Yellow'] 
lst3 = [1.1,1.8]  
lst4 = [1.0,1.2] 
case0 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2,lst3,lst4)), 
               columns =['Fruit', 'Color','shot1','shot2']) 

lst5 = ['Apple', 'Orange'] 
lst6 = ['Pink', 'Orange'] 
lst7 = [1.1,1.5]  
lst8 = [1.0,1.3] 
case1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst5, lst6,lst7,lst8)), 
               columns =['Fruit', 'Color','shot1','shot2'])
```

Does sqlalchemy have the ability to include relating table name into each columns as a tuple which can be easily transfer to multi-level columns in pandas later on?

Answer (score 0):

If we rename Case0 to First and Case1 to Second - I'm not sure SQL can handle numbers in table names, it sounds like it warrants the following SQL:

```
-- use coalesce to fill out the column if it is not present in first
SELECT coalesce(first.fruit, second.fruit) as fruit,
       coalesce(first.color, second.color) as color,
       first.shot1 as case1_shot1,
       first.shot2 as case1_shot2,
       second.shot1 as case2_shot1,
       second.shot2 as case2_shot2
FROM first
FULL OUTER JOIN second
  ON first.fruit = second.fruit
  AND first.color = second.color
```

And you can construct this using SQLAlchemy too:

```
session.query(
    func.coalesce(First.fruit, Second.fruit),
    func.coalesce(First.color, Second.color),
    First.shot1,
    First.shot2,
    Second.shot1,
    Second.shot2
).select_from(First).outerjoin(
    Second,
    (First.fruit == Second.fruit) & (First.color == Second.color),
    full=True
)
```

Since SQLAlchemy returns resultsets as tuples, it doesn't matter whether you name them or not, but since you explicitly set the ordering, you can just name them when you load them into a DataFrame.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(query.all(), columns=['Fruit', 'Color', 'case1shot1', 'case1shot2', 'case2shot1', 'case2shot2'])
```

I hope this answers your question